# A beam of given length subjected to a load (modeled by a differential equation)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I am self-studying numerical methods and this is a problem from the book I am using:

Let $x$ be the distance along the axis of the beam with $x= 0$ at the built-in end.  The variable $y$ measures the deflection of the beam.  It can be shown that the elastic deflections satisfy the differential equation 
\begin{align*}
y′′=\frac{F(L−x)[1 + (y′)^{2}]^{3/2}}{EI}
\end{align*}

where $E$ is Young’s modulus for the material and $I$ is the moment of inertia of a cross section of the beam.  Since both the deflection and its slope vanish at $x= 0$,  we have the initial conditions $y(0) = 0,   y′(0) = 0$. Use a numerical method of your choice to approximate $y(100)$ using $h= 2$ for the case of a beam of high-strength aluminum alloy with rectangular cross section.  The beam is 100 in.long and $I= 0.128 in^4$.  The value of Young’s modulus is $E= 1.0×10^7$ psi.  Solve the IVP for $F= 60,80,100,150$,and $200$ lbs to obtain some feeling about the deflection of the beam.

I wrote the given IVP as a system: I let $x=y'$, so that $x'=y''=\frac{F(L−x)[1 + x^{2}]^{3/2}}{EI}$, yielding the system (after plugging in the given values for $E, I, L$)
\begin{align*}
&y'=x, \qquad y(0)=0\\
&x'=\frac{F(100−x)[1 + x^{2}]^{3/2}}{10^{7}\cdot 0.128}, \qquad x(0)=0.
\end{align*}
I wrote a Runge-Kutta (order 4) code to solve the IVP for the given values of $F$. The output seems reasonable; since as the $x$ increases (i.e., the force is applied further along on the beam), the deflection increases, which is intuitive. Similarly, the deflection increases with force. I wanted to just double-check that my system is correct, etc. (and that my code seems fine; I'm new to it). The first few iterations of my MATLAB code with F=60:

`x             y

    0.00   0.00000
    2.00   0.03882
    4.00   0.15439
    6.00   0.34566
    8.00   0.61183
   10.00   0.95240
   12.00   1.36709
   14.00   1.85587
   16.00   2.41895
   18.00   3.05674
   20.00   3.76988
   22.00   4.55920
   24.00   5.42580
   26.00   6.37095
   28.00   7.39620
   30.00   8.50331`

If someone could double-check that this seems correct, I would appreciate it.

Comment: You're using the variable $x$ twice, once as the independent variable and once as a function of $x$. You should have something like $y_1(x)=y(x)$ and $y_2(x)=y_1'(x)=y'(x)$ and $y_2'(x)=(F(L-x)(1+y_2(x)^2)^{3/2})/(EI)$.

Comment: Oh, I see. In my code I changed things around: I was using $t$ as the distance along the axis of the beam, and in writing the system I introduced a variable $x$. So I had $y'=x$ and $x=(F(L-t)(1+x^{2})^{3/2})/(EI)$. Same thing, right?

Comment: Yeah that works.